# Multiple Labels displayed programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, label, viewdidload

I am a newbie at Swift, and I want to learn how to display six labels side by side programmatically. I have the code to display a single object, but I do not know how to expand it for more objects. The code I have is below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    private var label1: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 100)
    private var label2: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150)
    private var label3: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    private var label4: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250)
    private var label5: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300)
    private var label6: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 350, y: 350)
    
    // MARK: - View Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Add to View Hierarchy
        view.addSubview(pannableView) //This creates the object, how to send more than one object

        pannableView.center = view.center
        
        
        // Initialize Swipe Gesture Recognizer
        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPan(_:)))
        
        // Add Swipe Gesture Recognizer
        pannableView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    // MARK: -
    private let pannableView: UIView = {
        // Initialize View
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 80.0, height: 80.0))) //How big the object is
        
        // Configure View
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return view
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    @objc private func didPan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            label1 = pannableView.center
            
        case .changed:
            let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
            
            pannableView.center = CGPoint(x: label1.x + translation.x,
                                          y: label1.y + translation.y)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I assume I need to define all the labels I have done, but when it goes to pannableView, it will only display "label1". I have seen some posts that involve making a table, but I don't think this works because I need to drag the label across the entire screen. Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: Your code is a confused jumble. You have a bunch of vars called label1, label2, that don't contain labels, they contain CGRect values. You never seem to use the values you put in those variables initially, and then you only ever do something with the variable `label1`.  You have a var pannableView that you set to contain a single UIView. You have code that adds a pan gesture recognizer to your single pannableView. You don't tell us what that pan gesture recognizer is supposed to do. Is the user supposed to be able to drag around the views on the screen?

Comment: You need to clearly define, for yourself, what you are trying to do, and then you need to explain that in your question if we are to help you achieve it.

Comment: @DuncanC, I apologize for my messy code; I'm still learning swift. To answer your question, yes, the user is supposed to drag around the views on the screen. As you mentioned, I don't use the other variables, which I am stuck with. The pannableView only contains a single UIView, but I don't know how to expand it to contain multiple UIViews. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: How do you want the label views to be laid out on the screen initially? Also, you will need to make your code adjust their layout constraints if you want their locations to "stick" when the user drags them.

Comment: @DuncanC Basically, I want them to initially be on the right-hand side of the screen and then be draggable anywhere. If you could let me know how to make it so that pannableView contains multiple UIViews, that would be a great first step. I don't expect you to give me everything. I have determined the CGPoint at the top though ```let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 80.0, height: 80.0)))``` does seem to disregard that and put the UIView object at the center when I run the program

Comment: You want them all on top of each other on the righthand side of the screen? Or stacked vertically on the right-hand side? If they are piled together it will be visually confusing and hard for the user to tell which one they are grabbing when they try to grab one. Think this through in detail, storyboard out what you want to do before you try to implement it. If you don't have a clear idea of what you want to do, you won't be able to implement it.

Comment: @DuncanC thank you. I was able to think about what you said, started from scratch, and have made more progress. I have a new post in which my code is more streamlined, and I have a very clear question. If you have the time, check it out!

Comment: Can you post a link to your new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70477273/how-to-identify-what-gesturerecognizer-is-being-selected

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use UIStackView or UICollectionView of UIKit.
If you want to create your stack view from scratch for studying, you should create YourOwnStackView class inherit from UIView and constraint arranged subviews in there.

Comment: The OP wants the user to be able to drag the labels around on the screen. Stack views wouldn’t work for that.