# How to identify what gestureRecognizer is being selected

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, uipangesturerecognizer

I am working on a project where I programmatically create CGFloat objects that can be dragged while also programmatically creating target locations so the user can drag the object to the target location. Below is what I have, [image] I can drag the objects to the faded target location. The goal is that when I drag the blue CGFloat object to the target CGRect object, it will turn the faded blue target location into a solid blue only if it is dragged over the faded blue section. If not then, nothing happens.

Unfortunately, I am stuck because I don't know how to check if the draggable object correctly corresponds with the target section. If I drag a blue object over the red target, it will accept the dragged object and turn red.

Below is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private struct Constants {
        static let padding: CGFloat = 75
        static let correctPadding: CGFloat = 0
        static let blockDimension: CGFloat = 50
    }

    var targetView0: UIView?
    var targetView1: UIView?
    var targetView2: UIView?
    var targetView3: UIView?
    var targetView4: UIView?
    var targetView5: UIView?
    
    var beginningPosition: CGPoint = .zero
    var initialMovableViewPosition: CGPoint = .zero

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        addMovableViews(count: 6)
        addtargetView0()
        addtargetView1()
        addtargetView2()
        addtargetView3()
        addtargetView4()
        addtargetView5()
    }
    //This programtically creates the blocks w/ x and y
    private func addMovableViews(count: Int) {
        var xOffset = Constants.padding
        for i in 0..<count {
            print(i)
            let movableView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 700, y: xOffset + 120, width: Constants.blockDimension, height: Constants.blockDimension))
            if (i == 0) {
                movableView.backgroundColor = .blue
                view.addSubview(movableView)
                let item0 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touched(_:)))
                movableView.addGestureRecognizer(item0)
            } else if (i == 1) {
                movableView.backgroundColor = .red
                view.addSubview(movableView)
                let item1 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touched(_:)))
                movableView.addGestureRecognizer(item1)
                
            } else if (i == 2) {
                movableView.backgroundColor = .blue
                view.addSubview(movableView)
                let item2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touched(_:)))
                movableView.addGestureRecognizer(item2)
                
            } else if (i == 3) {
                movableView.backgroundColor = .red
                view.addSubview(movableView)
                let item3 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touched(_:)))
                movableView.addGestureRecognizer(item3)
                
            } else if (i == 4) {
                movableView.backgroundColor = .blue
                view.addSubview(movableView)
                let item4 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touched(_:)))
                movableView.addGestureRecognizer(item4)
                
            } else if (i == 5) {
                movableView.backgroundColor = .red
                view.addSubview(movableView)
                let item5 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touched(_:)))
                movableView.addGestureRecognizer(item5)
                
            } else if (i == 6) {
                movableView.backgroundColor = .blue
                view.addSubview(movableView)
                let item6 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touched(_:)))
                movableView.addGestureRecognizer(item6)
            }
            xOffset += Constants.blockDimension + Constants.padding
        }
        
    }
    
    private func addtargetView0() {
        let xOffset = Constants.correctPadding
        targetView0 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xOffset + 100, y: 500, width: Constants.blockDimension, height: Constants.blockDimension))
        targetView0?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 51/255.0, green: 153/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1)
        view.addSubview(targetView0!)
    }
    
    private func addtargetView1() {
        let xOffset = Constants.correctPadding
        targetView1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100 + xOffset + 50, y: 500, width: Constants.blockDimension, height: Constants.blockDimension))
        targetView1?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 102/255.0, blue: 102/255.0, alpha: 1)
        view.addSubview(targetView1!)
    }
    
    private func addtargetView2() {
        let xOffset = Constants.correctPadding
        targetView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100 + xOffset + 100, y: 500, width: Constants.blockDimension, height: Constants.blockDimension))
        targetView2?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 51/255.0, green: 153/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1)
        view.addSubview(targetView2!)
    }
    
    private func addtargetView3() {
        let xOffset = Constants.correctPadding
        targetView3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100 + xOffset + 150, y: 500, width: Constants.blockDimension, height: Constants.blockDimension))
        targetView3?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 102/255.0, blue: 102/255.0, alpha: 1)
        view.addSubview(targetView3!)
    }
    
    private func addtargetView4() {
        let xOffset = Constants.correctPadding
        targetView4 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100 + xOffset + 200, y: 500, width: Constants.blockDimension, height: Constants.blockDimension))
        targetView4?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 51/255.0, green: 153/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1)
        view.addSubview(targetView4!)
    }
    
    
    private func addtargetView5() {
        let xOffset = Constants.correctPadding
        targetView5 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100 + xOffset + 250, y: 500, width: Constants.blockDimension, height: Constants.blockDimension))
        targetView5?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 102/255.0, blue: 102/255.0, alpha: 1)
        view.addSubview(targetView5!)
    }

    //Gesture recognizer
    @objc private func touched(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let touchedView = gestureRecognizer.view {
            if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
                beginningPosition = gestureRecognizer.location(in: touchedView)
                initialMovableViewPosition = touchedView.frame.origin
            } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
                //Moves it back to where it was
//                touchedView.frame.origin = initialMovableViewPosition
                
            } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
                let locationInView = gestureRecognizer.location(in: touchedView)
                touchedView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: touchedView.frame.origin.x + locationInView.x - beginningPosition.x, y: touchedView.frame.origin.y + locationInView.y - beginningPosition.y)
                if touchedView.frame.intersects(targetView0!.frame) {
                    touchedView.removeFromSuperview() //Might uncomment when everything is set up so it deals with the overlay issue
//                    gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
                    targetView0?.backgroundColor = .blue
                    initialMovableViewPosition = .zero
                }
                if touchedView.frame.intersects(targetView1!.frame) {
                    touchedView.removeFromSuperview() //Might uncomment when everything is set up so it deals with the overlay issue
//                    gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
                    targetView1?.backgroundColor = .red
                    initialMovableViewPosition = .zero
                }
                if touchedView.frame.intersects(targetView2!.frame) {
                    touchedView.removeFromSuperview() //Might uncomment when everything is set up so it deals with the overlay issue
//                    gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
                    targetView2?.backgroundColor = .blue
                    initialMovableViewPosition = .zero
                }
                if touchedView.frame.intersects(targetView3!.frame) {
                    touchedView.removeFromSuperview() //Might uncomment when everything is set up so it deals with the overlay issue
//                    gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
                    targetView3?.backgroundColor = .red
                    initialMovableViewPosition = .zero
                }
                if touchedView.frame.intersects(targetView4!.frame) {
                    touchedView.removeFromSuperview() //Might uncomment when everything is set up so it deals with the overlay issue
//                    gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
                    targetView4?.backgroundColor = .blue
                    initialMovableViewPosition = .zero
                }
                if touchedView.frame.intersects(targetView5!.frame) {
                    touchedView.removeFromSuperview() //Might uncomment when everything is set up so it deals with the overlay issue
//                    gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
                    targetView5?.backgroundColor = .red
                    initialMovableViewPosition = .zero
                }
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I don't know how to check the gestureRecognizer object. I have tried doing gestureRecognizer.name but that returns null. The goal is to identify the color of the object being dragged and check it against which target the frames have intersected with and see if it is accepted or needs to be rejected. Any help on how to identify what object is being dragged would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Before you do anything else, you should rewrite your code to use an Array of UIView objects rather than your targetView0 - targetView5. Then collapse your multiple functions and repeated code to work through the array of view objects. Any time you write the same code over and over with just a different variable each time, it's a "code smell", an indication that there is a better way.

Comment: Your posted code that includes one reference to a UIGestureRecognizer, in the definition of your `touched(_:)` method. You don't show any code that sets up one or more gesture recognizers, nor do you tell us anything about how they are set up.

Comment: You need to write code that creates `UIGestureRecognizer` objects and attaches them to their views. I would suggest saving the gesture recognizers into an array. (Better yet, create an array that contains a `struct`  that holds both a view and its gesture recognizer. Then write code that goes through a loop and creates the views,  creates the gesture recognizers, attaches the gesture recognizers to their views, adds the views to the superview, and builds and saves structs into the array of view-plus-gesture-recoginzer struct.)

Comment: @DuncanC I completely agree with saving the gesture recognizers into an array. I updated my code above to declare 6 different objects. However, I think this points to my overall issue. When I pass the gesture recognizers into the function, addGestureRecognizer, how do I check to see if the gesture recognizer is unique? When I print gestureRecognizer, the output information doesn't seem to help. If you could tell me how to do that, I think I will be able to solve the issue.